# Can I make API call (router.post) inside another API call (router.post) in "index.js" File?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, http, request

for Example, Can I do API calls like the Below in nested form??

```
router.post('/',()=>
{
 res.send("Some File1");
   router.post('/',()=>{
     res.send("Some File2");
   })
})
```

Comment: What do you want?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not making API calls but creating API endpoints. This means you have created a REST endpoint at / with POST method.

```
router.post('/',(req, res) => {
 res.send("Some File1");
});
```

Comment: Yeah @kiran Mathew, Can I do this as Nested Format .. Like router.post inside a router.post ??

Comment: @AndiswamyRajagopal Why would you want to do that? If you post your requirement, maybe I would be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snipet, hope it will worked.

```
router.post('/')
   .then((data) => {
      res.send({
         dataField1,dataField2
       })
     })
    .then(() => {
      return router.post('/')
    })
    .then((data2) => {
      res.send({
       data2Field1, data2Field
     });
    })
```